# Insert special characters from PHP to Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have just created a MSSQL database.
The collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS.
I use it from a Linux-Apache-PHP server using freetds.
When I receive text from a web form, and I try to insert text containing special characters (e.g. café), I get an error.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', '1') ;
$MyConn = mssql_connect( "MSPROD", "one", "1a!logas1" ) ;
mssql_select_db( "SIAM", $MyConn ) ;
if ( isset( $_GET['arg'] ) )
    {
    $arg = $_GET['arg'] ;
    print "Inserting '$arg'<br>\n" ;
    for ( $i = 0 ; $i < strlen( $arg ) ; $i ++ )
        {
        print dechex( ord( $arg{$i} ) ) . ' ' ;
        }
    mssql_query( "INSERT mytest VALUES('$arg')" ) ;
    }
?>
<form action=badchars.php method=get>
<input type=text name=arg>
</form>
```

This is the error:

> Inserting 'café' 63 61 66 e9 Warning: mssql_query(): Sybase: Server
>   message: Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'caf'.
>   (severity 15, procedure N/A) in /www/one/mytest/badchars.php on
>   line 13 Warning: mssql_query(): Sybase: Server message: Incorrect
>   syntax near 'caf'. (severity 15, procedure N/A) in
>   /www/one/mytest/badchars.php on line 13

The fact that it mentions Sybase is because the server was installed for it initially, but it is my understanding that the Sybase and Mssql functions are identical, so it should not matter.
If I try to put the text strainght into the quotes, I still get the same error:

```
mssql_query( "INSERT mytest VALUES('café')" ) ;
```

But, if I run the same query in SQL Server Manager it works!
This works:

```
mssql_query( "INSERT mytest VALUES('caf' + char(233) )" ) ;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL, not mysql.
And the problem is not about quoting, I think.

Comment: I apologise; I misread your question

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to stop using php_mssql, instead get `Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server` and almost any problems that we have in php_mssql will be solved, you will have **a lot of troubles** in sending and getting UTF-8 data to and from SQL Server using php_mssql.

You will have to CAST nText and nVarchar while selecting to Text and Varchar because php_mssql only support old SQL Server drivers ...

If you really need to use php_mssql, you have to use `iconv` and maybe `utf8_decode`. Here are 2 functions that I wrote to store and get UTF-8 Persian/Arabic data in SQL Server.

```
function persian_sql_to_php($str){
    if(mb_detect_encoding($str) == 'UTF-8' AND mb_check_encoding($str, 'UTF-8')){
        $str = utf8_decode($str);
    }
    $str = iconv('Windows-1256', 'UTF-8', $str);
    return $str;
}

function persian_php_to_sql($str){
    $str = iconv('UTF-8', 'Windows-1256', $str);
    return $str;
}
```

You will need to change Windows-1256 to something else depending on the language you are using. Also try `utf8_decode` and `utf8_encode` alone, maybe they work for your case.

**Update:**

Since you are using FreeTDS, the situation maybe differ a little from main php_mssql that I explained above about it's problems with UTF-8 ...

**Update 2:**
I just tried this code on Windows and it seems to work, can you try it too, maybe it works for you too?

```
<?php

mssql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'sa', '123456');
mssql_select_db('test');

$val = 'café';

$val = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1', $val);

mssql_query('INSERT INTO mytest (test) VALUES (\''.$val.'\');');

?>
```

Comment: My PHP server is Linux, can I use "Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server" there? I guess not, but I would use it as possible.

Comment: I'm not sure about this one, but I know they have a SQL Server ODBC driver for linux, so maybe using php ODBC and their ODBC driver could be an alternative way too.

Comment: I don't think UTF-8 plays a role here.
If the collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS it means the database is not using UTF-8, am I correct?
And if I analyze the word café that I am trying to pass to database, it seems to be 4 characters. If it were UTF-8 it would be longer, right?

Comment: `echo strlen('café'); // 5` Your `é` character is UTF-8, it can be saved as ANSI too, but it should be converted before the send, and also converted back after the get, that's why you should use `iconv` or `utf8_encode` ... As you mentioned yourself when using char(233) which is it's ANSI equal, you get no error ...

Comment: The reason you are getting 4 is because your php file is saved as ANSI, save your file as UTF-8 without BOM to get the real result ...

Comment: Maybe you need to set the characterset of the headers of the page posting aswell as the connection to the database and the collation?

Comment: Just a note, you will get to nowhere by talking in here, you should start trying the functions I mentioned with different parameters until you get a result, those 2 functions work for Persian/Arabic and it took me weeks to get to those few simple lines ...

Comment: I added something to answer, please try it too.